# QGIS 3.4 Vertex tool highlight colour change

Tags: qgis, color, vertices

I can change the colour for selected items fine. I have even figured out how to change the colour of the preview when moving a vertex. How can I change the colour of the highlight when hovering over a feature with the vertex tool?

The default is red and the line features I most commonly work with are also red so I was really hoping there was a way to change this to make seeing the vertex I'm about to select easier.

Comment: Did you have a look at `Menu Settings / Options / Digitizing` ?

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Setting -> Options -> Digitizing -> Rubberband` section and change the color to the desired one. When finished, restart QGIS, and it will use the new color when highlighting the line using the vertex tool.

In this example, I changed the highlight color from the default red color to green color, then restarted QGIS:

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]